# Showing that there's no solution to the congruence $x^{2}+3y^{2}\equiv2\mod3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I was given the following question:

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$, show that the congruence $x^{2}+3y^{2}\equiv2\mod3$ has no solution.

Here's my attempt so far:

$x^{2}+3y^{2}\equiv2\mod3$

$\Rightarrow x^{2}+3y^{2}-2\equiv0\mod3$

Thus: $3\mid x^{2}+3y^{2}-2$

Therefore the summation have to be divisible by 3, so we can exclude $3y^{2}$.

Now, let's assume by contradiction that there's a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^{2}-2=3k$.

$\Rightarrow x^{2}-2-3k=0$

And I don't know how to continue.

Am I doing something wrong? What is the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  $3y^2\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ so your congruence is just $x^2\equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I've tried that also. I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Well, there are only $3$ values $x$ can take.   Do any of those values satisfy $x^2\equiv 2\pmod 3$?

Comment: @lulu Thank you! I don't know how I missed that one :)

Comment: The notation should be $3 \mid x^{2}+3y^{2}-2$ (but you have the correct meaning)

Comment: @Sil Whoops, my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

You just need to prove that there is no $ x\in \Bbb N$ such that

$$x^2\equiv 2 \pmod 3$$.

Let $ x \in \Bbb N$.

$$x=0\implies x^2\equiv 0\mod 3$$
$$x=1\implies x^2\equiv 1\mod 3$$
$$x=2\implies x^2\equiv 1\mod 3$$
assume that $x\ge 3$.

If $x \equiv 0\mod 3 $ then $x^2\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

If $ x$ is not a multiple of $3$, then
$gcd(x,3)=1$ and by Fermat's Little theorem
$$x^{\phi(3)}=x^2\equiv 1 \mod 3$$

Done.